# How to avoid global class declaration in main.cpp

Tags: c++, class

I have question about best practice to avoiding global class declaration in main.cpp. Now I have code similar to this:

```
...
auto config = std::make_unique<ConfigReader>();
auto control = std::make_unique<Control>();
...

void function()
{
   //do something with config;
}
main()
{
   //do something with config and control;
}
```

I wonder what is the best idea to avoid declare global config and control in top of the file. Should I create new class (for example SystemRun), put all the things there and in main function call something like SystemRun::Run()?

Or maybe there are some better solutions? I know how to write working code but I want to know how to write it in optimal way.

Comment: *"optimal way"* - That's to vague of a term. What do you wish to optimal exactly?

Comment: You say "class" when you mean "object" or "class instance".

Comment: If something is used globally, it can of course be declared and defined globally. You would wrap the variables in a namespace of course, but if you need something to be accessible from multiple functions (members or non-members) then they need to be defined in a location where all functions can use them.

Comment: You didn't say if you need them to exist outside main scope. Would it work if you put "static" in front of them (file scope)? Is function only called from main (everything is main scope)? Will you want a unit test for function() (reason to refactor)?

Comment: Are you facing an actual problem, or are you just doing this because somebody told you that "globals are bad"? Don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: The thing you might want to think about is: Can it be implemented as local variables, and passed as arguments to functions that need them?

Comment: It seems a bit unusual to have a `unique_ptr` as a global variable. If the object is global and lives throughout the entire program lifetime, there is hardly any questions about ownership.

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean objects of course. And yes it worked now but I hear that I shouldn't use globals.